# Problems in client server application when using malloc to allocate buffer

Tags: c, sockets, malloc

I am working on a project including server-client communication.
Our code doesn't work all the time, sometimes it works perfectly. But sometimes we either get a timeout or our buffer doesn't work properly. Thats why we want to implement `malloc()`. Do you think this could help?
our code before `malloc()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BUFFERSIZE 1024                                              
#define VERSION "VERSION 3.4\n"

#include "functions.h"

char buffer[BUFFERSIZE];

void resetBuffer(char *buffer) {
    memset((buffer), '\0', strlen(buffer));
}

void receiveAnswer(int sock) {
    resetBuffer(buffer);
    size_t length;
    bool x = true;

    while (x) {
        recv(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
        length = strlen(buffer);
        if (buffer[length-1]  == '\n') {
            x = false;
        }
    }

    if (buffer[0] == '-') {
        printf("Error: %s", buffer);
    } else {
        printf("%s\n ", buffer);
    }
}

void sendResponse(int sock, char *message) {
    resetBuffer(buffer);
    strcpy(buffer, message);

    bool x = true;
    size_t length;

    while(x) {
        send(sock, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
        length = strlen(buffer);
        if (buffer[length - 1] == '\n') {
            x = false;
        }
    }

    printf("Client: %s\n", buffer);
}

int performConnection(int sock, char *gameID) {
    receiveAnswer(sock);
    sleep(1);
    receiveAnswer(sock);
    sleep(1);
    sendResponse(sock, VERSION);
    sleep(1);
    receiveAnswer(sock);
    sleep(1);
    sendResponse(sock, gameID);
    sleep(1);
    receiveAnswer(sock);
    sleep(1);
    sendResponse(sock, "PLAYER \n");
    sleep(1);
    receiveAnswer(sock);

    resetBuffer(buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

Our code with `malloc()` doesn't work at all anymore:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BUFFERSIZE 1024
#define VERSION "VERSION 3.4\n"

#include "functions.h"

char *buffer;

void resetBuffer(char *buffer) {
    memset((buffer), '\0', strlen(buffer));
}

void receiveAnswer(int sock) {
    resetBuffer(buffer);
    size_t length;
    bool x = true;

    while (x) {
        recv(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
        length = strlen(buffer);
        if (buffer[length-1] == '\n') {
            x = false;
        }
    }

    if (buffer[0] == '-') {
        printf("Error: %s", buffer);
    } else {
        printf("%s\n ", buffer);
    }
}

void sendResponse(int sock, char *message) {
    resetBuffer(buffer);
    strcpy(buffer, message);

    bool x = true;
    size_t length;

    while (x) {
        send(sock, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
        length = strlen(buffer);
        if (buffer[length - 1] == '\n') {
            x = false;
        }
    }

    printf("Client: %s\n", buffer);
}

int performConnection(int sock, char *gameID) {
    buffer = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * BUFFERSIZE);
    receiveAnswer(sock);
    sleep(1);
    receiveAnswer(sock);
    sleep(1);
    sendResponse(sock, VERSION);
    sleep(1);
    receiveAnswer(sock);
    sleep(1);
    sendResponse(sock, gameID);
    sleep(1);
    receiveAnswer(sock);
    sleep(1);
    sendResponse(sock, "PLAYER \n");
    sleep(1);
    receiveAnswer(sock);

    resetBuffer(buffer);
    free(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Any help is appreciated!
Best Enno

Comment: What makes you think that "implementing malloc" will help with a "timeout" problem?

Comment: ```malloc``` isn't magic.

Comment: In the receive function, when `buffer` was an array, `sizeof` was useful. In the second version, `sizeof buffer` is now the size of a pointer, not the size of the buffer that it points to... (PS: `malloc()` can fail... It'd be a good idea to verify it succceeded.)

Comment: Aside: It's redundant to cast the result of ```malloc```.

Comment: The memory returned by ```malloc``` is always uninitialized. Perhaps use ```calloc```?

Comment: No need no ```x```, ```while (true)``` suffices.

Comment: ```recv``` and ```send``` aren't guaranteed to receive and send all the bytes in one go, the convention is to call them in a loop until they do.

Comment: ```recv```, ```send```, and ```malloc``` all return error codes. Check for them.

Comment: @Haris "_Perhaps use calloc?_"... That would work ahead of the first use of the buffer. And after that??

Comment: @Fe2O3 Touché..

Answer (score 1):

`resetBuffer(buffer);` fails as it attempts `strlen(buffer)` on uninitialized data.    This invokes *undefined behavior* (UB) as `strlen()` expects a pointer to a *string*.

Instead:

```
// resetBuffer(buffer);
memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(char)* BUFFERSIZE);
// or simply
memset(buffer, 0, BUFFERSIZE);
```

Answer (score 1):

this

```
void resetBuffer(char* buffer){
   memset((buffer), '\0', strlen(buffer));
}
```

is undefined behavior. It depends of the previous contents of buffer (strlen looks for 0 terminator)

you need to pass in a length (not got from strlen)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you bothering with the function `reset_buffer()` at all?

Each invocation appears immediately ahead of, for instance, `strcpy()`. The latter doesn't care if the buffer has be "reset". (Hopefully the buffer is large enough to hold what is being put into it.)

The last invocation appears immediately ahead of `free()`. Again, the content of the buffer is irrelevant.

More of a worry is that `buffer[]` has become `*buffer`... The `sizeof(buffer)` in the receive function is now telling `recv` there are 8 bytes available (the size of a pointer on your machine) to be filled, not the 1024 bytes of the "pre-malloc" version.

Change:

```
void receiveAnswer (int sock){
// ...
        recv(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
```

to

```
        recv(sock, buffer, BUFFERSIZE, 0);
```

This is not a MRE, so this "fix", while correct, may not be the entire solution.

Answer (score 0):

`buffer` does not necessarily contain a proper C string, hence using `strlen` to compute the number of bytes received is incorrect: use the return value of `recv` instead. Similarly, the buffer clearing function should either get the length as an argument or use `BUFFER_SIZE`.

Whether `buffer` is defined as a global array of bytes or allocated from the heap before use does not matter, and your code has nothing to do with *implementing* the `malloc` function.